# Why does this error pop up in the slash command thing?

Tags: node.js, discord, autocode

this is the slash command:

const lib = require('lib')({token: process.env.STDLIB_SECRET_TOKEN});

```js
await lib.discord.commands['@0.0.0'].create({
  "guild_id": "1018895233003569193",
  "name": "submit-hw",
  "description": "trimite tema",
  "options": [
    {
      "type": 3,
      "name": "materie",
      "description": "",
      "choices": [
        {
          "name": "romana",
          "value": "romana"
        },
        {
          "name": "mate",
          "value": "mate"
        },
        {
          "name": "religie",
          "value": "religie"
        },
        {
          "name": "engleza",
          "value": "engleza"
        },
        {
          "name": "franceza",
          "value": "franceza"
        },
        {
          "name": "desen",
          "value": "desen"
        },
        {
          "name": "sport",
          "value": "sport"
        },
        {
          "name": "biologie",
          "value": "biologie"
        },
        {
          "name": "fizica",
          "value": "fizica"
        },
        {
          "name": "tic",
          "value": "tic"
        },
        {
          "name": "istorie",
          "value": "istorie"
        },
        {
          "name": "chimie",
          "value": "chimie"
        },
        {
          "name": "consiliere",
          "value": "consiliere"
        },
        {
          "name": "sociala",
          "value": "sociala"
        },
        {
          "name": "optional",
          "value": "optional"
        },
        {
          "name": "tehnologica",
          "value": "tehnologica"
        },
        {
          "name": "geografie",
          "value": "geografie"
        },
        {
          "name": "muzica",
          "value": "muzica"
        }
      ],
      "required": true
    },
    {
      "type": 3,
      "name": "deadline",
      "description": "",
      "required": true
    },
    {
      "type": 3,
      "name": "tema",
      "description": "",
      "required": true
    }
  ]
});
```

and this is the error

[image: the error]

It says:

Sorry, could not save you slash commands: Invalid Form Body: code 50035:

Can someone help me out? I wrote all of the command options in the ui text boxes, not as code. SO won't let me post this without more string of text thats not code and i have no idea what to type.....

Answer (score 0):

Description is required for all slash commands and options, including subcommands and subcommand groups. Just a heads up, Error code 50035 would go into detail to show which part is causing an error, such as one of the options type being incorrect.